# What does "then because of" mean?

Tags: meaning

> If you feel you need to work overtime, then because of your position
>   or salary level, you won’t be paid additional overtime.

What does "then because of" mean? I searched dictionaries, but couldn't find any relevant information.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is missing a comma to make complete sense:

> If you feel you need to work overtime, then, because of your position or salary level, you won’t be paid additional overtime.

Without the word then "then" it isn't clear whether the position or salary is the reason for feeling the need to work overtime or the reason for not receiving additional pay, which is what it actually seems to be.

*Consider these statements in isolation:*

> I need to work overtime because of my salary.

This means your salary is your motivation for working overtime.

> Because of my salary I am not paid for overtime.

This means that your salary is the reason you are not paid overtime.

Hopefully this helps explain why the sentence needs punctuating the way it has been in order to make it clear on which clause the salary is an influence.